# Docker Nvidia GPU tensorflow pywrap initialization failed

Tags: docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

I want to run tensorflow inside a Docker `Docker version 20.10.21, build 20.10.21-0ubuntu1~20.04.2` image, but whenever I import tensor-flow I get an error:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 26 2023, 14:05:08) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
2023-06-20 16:52:48.161165: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xe but this version of numpy is 0xd
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError: <built-in method __contains__ of dict object at 0x7fdd46d10a00> returned a result with an error set

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 34, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/pywrap_tf_session.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client._pywrap_tf_session import *
ImportError: initialization failed
>>>
```

Can you please tell me how can I solve this issue?

My `Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV cudnn_version=8.5.0.96
ENV cuda_version=cuda11.7

# Set keyboard-configuration package selections
RUN echo 'keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/layoutcode string us' | debconf-set-selections \
    && echo 'keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/layout select' | debconf-set-selections \
    && echo 'keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/variantcode string ' | debconf-set-selections \
    && echo 'keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/variant select ' | debconf-set-selections \
    && echo 'keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/modelcode string ' | debconf-set-selections \
    && echo 'keyboard-configuration keyboard-configuration/model select ' | debconf-set-selections

# Install additional ROS packages and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    cmake build-essential git libgtk2.0-dev \
    pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev \
    libswscale-dev software-properties-common \
    wget curl keyboard-configuration libpcl-dev \
    libeigen3-dev libopencv-dev libopencv-dev \
    python3-opencv gnupg2 lsb-release curl \
    python3 python3-pip 

# Add the ROS package repository and key
RUN curl -sSL "http://packages.ros.org/ros.key" | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list

# Update the package lists and install ROS Desktop Full
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ros-noetic-desktop-full \
    ros-noetic-libfranka \
    ros-noetic-franka-ros \
    python3-rosdep python3-catkin-tools python3-osrf-pycommon \
    libnlopt-dev libnlopt-cxx-dev libopenni2-dev \
    libusb-1.0-0-dev libudev-dev openjdk-8-jdk \
    freeglut3-dev

ENV ROS_DISTRO noetic

# Source the ROS environment
RUN echo "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash" >> /root/.bashrc

# Install CUDA and CuDNN (if required)
# Instructions for installing CUDA and CuDNN vary based on the version you need.

# Install CUDA 11.7.0 driver (this part to be tested again)
RUN wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.7.0/local_installers/cuda_11.7.0_515.43.04_linux.run
RUN chmod +x cuda_11.7.0_515.43.04_linux.run && sudo ./cuda_11.7.0_515.43.04_linux.run --silent --toolkit && rm cuda_11.7.0_515.43.04_linux.run

## CUDA path
RUN echo "export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}" >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}" >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/belal/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> /root/.bashrc

## Python Path
RUN echo "export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${HOME}:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages" >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo "export PATH=\"/usr/local/bin:/home/belal/.local/bin:$PATH\"" >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo "export PYTHONWARNINGS=\"ignore:Unverified HTTPS request\"" >> /root/.bashrc

## Install CuDNN 8.9.2
## Replace the URL below with the appropriate URL for CuDNN 8.9.2 download
# RUN wget https://developer.nvidia.com/downloads/compute/cudnn/secure/8.9.2/local_installers/11.x/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.2.26_1.0-1_amd64.deb \
#     && dpkg -i cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.2.26_1.0-1_amd64.deb && apt-get update && apt-get install -y cudnn8 \
#    && rm cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2004-8.9.2.26_1.0-1_amd64.deb \
#    && cp cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/include \
#    && cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64 \
#    && chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn*.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*

RUN wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin \
    && mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600 \
    && apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/3bf863cc.pub \
    && add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/ /" \
    && apt-get update

RUN apt-get install libcudnn8=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}
RUN apt-get install libcudnn8-dev=${cudnn_version}-1+${cuda_version}
RUN sudo apt install -y nvidia-cuda-toolkit

# OpenNI2 Install
RUN wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/com.occipital.openni/OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2.0.33.tar.bz2
RUN tar -xvf OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2.0.33.tar.bz2
RUN rm OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2.0.33.tar.bz2
RUN cd OpenNI-Linux-x64-2.2 && sudo ./install.sh

# Install compatible TensorFlow version
RUN pip install tensorflow==2.11.0
RUN pip install mediapipe
RUN pip install opencv-python
RUN pip install open3d
RUN pip install openni
RUN pip install hmmlearn
```

Here is a list of the installed packages:

```
Package                       Version             
----------------------------- --------------------
absl-py                       1.4.0               
actionlib                     1.14.0              
addict                        2.4.0               
aiofiles                      22.1.0              
aiosqlite                     0.19.0              
angles                        1.9.13              
anyio                         3.7.0               
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0              
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0              
asttokens                     2.2.1               
astunparse                    1.6.3               
attrs                         19.3.0              
autobahn                      17.10.1             
Automat                       0.8.0               
Babel                         2.12.1              
backcall                      0.2.0               
bcrypt                        3.1.7               
beautifulsoup4                4.12.2              
bleach                        6.0.0               
blinker                       1.4                 
bondpy                        1.8.6               
cachetools                    5.3.1               
camera-calibration            1.17.0              
camera-calibration-parsers    1.12.0              
catkin                        0.8.10              
catkin-pkg                    0.5.2               
catkin-pkg-modules            0.5.2               
catkin-tools                  0.9.2               
cbor                          1.0.0               
certifi                       2019.11.28          
cffi                          1.15.1              
chardet                       3.0.4               
charset-normalizer            3.1.0               
Click                         7.0                 
colorama                      0.4.3               
comm                          0.1.3               
constantly                    15.1.0              
controller-manager            0.19.6              
controller-manager-msgs       0.19.6              
cryptography                  2.8                 
cupshelpers                   1.0                 
cv-bridge                     1.16.2              
cycler                        0.10.0              
Cython                        0.29.14             
dbus-python                   1.2.16              
debugpy                       1.6.7               
decorator                     5.1.1               
defer                         1.0.6               
defusedxml                    0.6.0               
deprecation                   2.1.0               
diagnostic-analysis           1.11.0              
diagnostic-common-diagnostics 1.11.0              
diagnostic-updater            1.11.0              
distro                        1.4.0               
distro-info                   0.23ubuntu1         
docutils                      0.16                
dynamic-reconfigure           1.7.3               
empy                          3.3.2               
entrypoints                   0.3                 
exceptiongroup                1.1.1               
executing                     1.2.0               
fastjsonschema                2.17.1              
flatbuffers                   23.5.26             
gast                          0.4.0               
gazebo-plugins                2.9.2               
gazebo-ros                    2.9.2               
gencpp                        0.7.0               
geneus                        3.0.0               
genlisp                       0.4.18              
genmsg                        0.6.0               
gennodejs                     2.0.2               
genpy                         0.6.15              
google-auth                   2.20.0              
google-auth-oauthlib          0.4.6               
google-pasta                  0.2.0               
grpcio                        1.54.2              
h5py                          3.9.0               
hmmlearn                      0.3.0               
httplib2                      0.14.0              
hyperlink                     19.0.0              
idna                          2.8                 
image-geometry                1.16.2              
importlib-metadata            1.5.0               
importlib-resources           5.12.0              
incremental                   16.10.1             
interactive-markers           1.12.0              
ipykernel                     6.23.2              
ipython                       8.12.2              
ipython-genutils              0.2.0               
ipywidgets                    8.0.6               
jedi                          0.18.2              
Jinja2                        3.1.2               
joblib                        1.2.0               
joint-state-publisher         1.15.1              
joint-state-publisher-gui     1.15.1              
json5                         0.9.14              
jsonschema                    4.17.3              
jupyter-client                8.2.0               
jupyter-core                  5.3.1               
jupyter-events                0.6.3               
jupyter-packaging             0.12.3              
jupyter-server                2.6.0               
jupyter-server-fileid         0.9.0               
jupyter-server-terminals      0.4.4               
jupyter-server-ydoc           0.8.0               
jupyter-ydoc                  0.2.4               
jupyterlab                    3.6.4               
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2               
jupyterlab-server             2.23.0              
jupyterlab-widgets            3.0.7               
keras                         2.11.0              
keyring                       18.0.1              
kiwisolver                    1.0.1               
language-selector             0.1                 
laser-geometry                1.6.7               
launchpadlib                  1.10.13             
lazr.restfulclient            0.14.2              
lazr.uri                      1.0.3               
libclang                      16.0.0              
lz4                           3.0.2+dfsg          
macaroonbakery                1.3.1               
Markdown                      3.4.3               
MarkupSafe                    2.1.3               
matplotlib                    3.1.2               
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6               
mediapipe                     0.10.1              
message-filters               1.16.0              
mistune                       3.0.1               
more-itertools                4.2.0               
mpi4py                        3.0.3               
nbclassic                     1.0.0               
nbclient                      0.8.0               
nbconvert                     7.6.0               
nbformat                      5.9.0               
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6               
netifaces                     0.10.4              
nose                          1.3.7               
notebook                      6.5.4               
notebook-shim                 0.2.3               
numpy                         1.23.5              
oauthlib                      3.1.0               
olefile                       0.46                
open3d                        0.13.0              
opencv-contrib-python         4.7.0.72            
opencv-python                 4.7.0.72            
openni                        2.3.0               
opt-einsum                    3.3.0               
osrf-pycommon                 2.0.2               
overrides                     7.3.1               
packaging                     23.1                
pandas                        2.0.2               
pandocfilters                 1.5.0               
paramiko                      2.6.0               
parso                         0.8.3               
pexpect                       4.8.0               
pickleshare                   0.7.5               
Pillow                        7.0.0               
pip                           20.0.2              
pkgutil-resolve-name          1.3.10              
platformdirs                  3.6.0               
prometheus-client             0.17.0              
prompt-toolkit                3.0.38              
protobuf                      3.19.5              
psutil                        5.5.1               
ptyprocess                    0.7.0               
pure-eval                     0.2.2               
py-ubjson                     0.14.0              
pyasn1                        0.4.2               
pyasn1-modules                0.2.1               
pycairo                       1.16.2              
pycparser                     2.21                
pycryptodomex                 3.6.1               
pycups                        1.9.73              
pydot                         1.4.1               
Pygments                      2.3.1               
PyGObject                     3.36.0              
PyHamcrest                    1.9.0               
PyJWT                         1.7.1               
pymacaroons                   0.13.0              
PyNaCl                        1.3.0               
PyOpenGL                      3.1.0               
pyOpenSSL                     19.0.0              
pyparsing                     2.4.6               
pypng                         0.0.20              
PyQRCode                      1.2.1               
PyQt5                         5.14.1              
pyRFC3339                     1.1                 
pyrsistent                    0.19.3              
python-apt                    2.0.1+ubuntu0.20.4.1
python-dateutil               2.7.3               
python-gnupg                  0.4.5               
python-json-logger            2.0.7               
python-qt-binding             0.4.4               
python-snappy                 0.5.3               
PyTrie                        0.2                 
pytz                          2019.3              
pywrap                        0.1.0               
PyYAML                        5.3.1               
pyzmq                         25.1.0              
qt-dotgraph                   0.4.2               
qt-gui                        0.4.2               
qt-gui-cpp                    0.4.2               
qt-gui-py-common              0.4.2               
requests                      2.22.0              
requests-oauthlib             1.3.1               
requests-unixsocket           0.2.0               
resource-retriever            1.12.7              
rfc3339-validator             0.1.4               
rfc3986-validator             0.1.1               
roman                         2.0.0               
rosbag                        1.16.0              
rosboost-cfg                  1.15.8              
rosclean                      1.15.8              
roscreate                     1.15.8              
rosdep                        0.22.2              
rosdep-modules                0.22.2              
rosdistro-modules             0.9.0               
rosgraph                      1.16.0              
roslaunch                     1.16.0              
roslib                        1.15.8              
roslint                       0.12.0              
roslz4                        1.16.0              
rosmake                       1.15.8              
rosmaster                     1.16.0              
rosmsg                        1.16.0              
rosnode                       1.16.0              
rosparam                      1.16.0              
rospkg                        1.5.0               
rospkg-modules                1.5.0               
rospy                         1.16.0              
rosservice                    1.16.0              
rostest                       1.16.0              
rostopic                      1.16.0              
rosunit                       1.15.8              
roswtf                        1.16.0              
rqt-action                    0.4.9               
rqt-bag                       0.5.1               
rqt-bag-plugins               0.5.1               
rqt-console                   0.4.11              
rqt-dep                       0.4.12              
rqt-graph                     0.4.14              
rqt-gui                       0.5.3               
rqt-gui-py                    0.5.3               
rqt-image-view                0.4.17              
rqt-launch                    0.4.9               
rqt-logger-level              0.4.11              
rqt-moveit                    0.5.10              
rqt-msg                       0.4.10              
rqt-nav-view                  0.5.7               
rqt-plot                      0.4.13              
rqt-pose-view                 0.5.11              
rqt-publisher                 0.4.10              
rqt-py-common                 0.5.3               
rqt-py-console                0.4.10              
rqt-reconfigure               0.5.5               
rqt-robot-dashboard           0.5.8               
rqt-robot-monitor             0.5.14              
rqt-robot-steering            0.5.12              
rqt-runtime-monitor           0.5.9               
rqt-rviz                      0.7.0               
rqt-service-caller            0.4.10              
rqt-shell                     0.4.11              
rqt-srv                       0.4.9               
rqt-tf-tree                   0.6.3               
rqt-top                       0.4.10              
rqt-topic                     0.4.13              
rqt-web                       0.4.10              
rsa                           4.9                 
rviz                          1.14.20             
scikit-learn                  1.2.2               
scipy                         1.10.1              
SecretStorage                 2.3.1               
Send2Trash                    1.8.2               
sensor-msgs                   1.13.1              
service-identity              18.1.0              
setuptools                    45.2.0              
simplejson                    3.16.0              
sip                           4.19.21             
six                           1.14.0              
smach                         2.5.1               
smach-ros                     2.5.1               
smclib                        1.8.6               
sniffio                       1.3.0               
sounddevice                   0.4.6               
soupsieve                     2.4.1               
stack-data                    0.6.2               
systemd-python                234                 
tensorboard                   2.11.2              
tensorboard-data-server       0.6.1               
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1               
tensorflow                    2.11.0              
tensorflow-estimator          2.11.0              
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.32.0              
termcolor                     2.3.0               
terminado                     0.17.1              
tf                            1.13.2              
tf-conversions                1.13.2              
tf2-geometry-msgs             0.7.6               
tf2-kdl                       0.7.6               
tf2-py                        0.7.6               
tf2-ros                       0.7.6               
threadpoolctl                 3.1.0               
tinycss2                      1.2.1               
tomli                         2.0.1               
tomlkit                       0.11.8              
topic-tools                   1.16.0              
tornado                       6.3.2               
tqdm                          4.65.0              
traitlets                     5.9.0               
Twisted                       18.9.0              
txaio                         2.10.0              
typing-extensions             4.6.3               
tzdata                        2023.3              
u-msgpack-python              2.1                 
unattended-upgrades           0.1                 
urllib3                       1.25.8              
wadllib                       1.3.3               
wcwidth                       0.2.6               
webencodings                  0.5.1               
websocket-client              1.6.0               
Werkzeug                      2.3.6               
wheel                         0.40.0              
widgetsnbextension            4.0.7               
wrapt                         1.15.0              
wsaccel                       0.6.2               
xacro                         1.14.16             
y-py                          0.5.9               
ypy-websocket                 0.8.4               
zipp                          1.0.0               
zope.interface                4.7.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to **Upgrade numpy** from the default version `1.17.4` to `1.23.1`